# Writing an object to a file when other threads are modifying the object

Tags: java

All,

I am writing a multithread program. The class which extends Thread has a `static Hashtalbe<Integer, SessionData> sessionDataTable`.

In the class, I will do something to change the sessionDataTable, like insert a new SessionData object into it, delete a SessionData object from it or modified the SessionData objects in the Hashtable.

At the end, I will write the Hashtable to a file using ObjectOutputStream, the method is something like

```
public static synchronized void saveDataSessionState()
{
    ...
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Constants.logFile));
    oos.writeObject(sessionDataTable);
    ...
}
```

I am wondering what will happen if one thread is doing `oos.writeObject(sessionDataTable);` but other threads are modifying the sessionDataTable (like what I said above) at the same time somewhere outside this method. Will the above method cause exception when writing the object to file?

If yes, how could I avoid the problem? Use lock? But then I need to put a lock whenever I modify the Hashtable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my examination of the code, I think that you won't have any problems.  The accessors and mutators for the `Hashtable` class are declared as `synchronized`, and so is the private `writeObject` method on `Hashtable` that does the serialization.  That should be sufficient to ensure that nothing can change the `Hashtable` while the serializer is looking at it.

However, you could get into trouble if something changed the state of a `Hashtable` key or value while serialization was occurring.  (I don't know if default serialization of an object is performed holding an object's mutex.  I suspect not because of the cost of locking  unnecessarily, the fact that a simple mutex won't necessarily achieve the required exclusive access, and the potential risk of deadlocks.)

Answer (score 1):

[ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is what you need. This, however, will solve only the hash map concurrent access issue.

At the same time the SessionData would need to be made immutable, which would ensure that a particular instance would never change once created. If a hash map entry needs to be modified -- simply replace it with a new instance of SessionData.